# What happens if two players reach the showdown and one of them is out of chips?

Tags: texas-hold-em, all-in

When there are two remaining players in Texas Holden, and one of them has gone all in on the turn, what happens if the other player calls and the river is dealt? There’s one player with no chips left and the other still with chips. One cannot bet and if the other bets, the player with no chips cannot call. Do both show their hand at this point?

Comment: on the turn, there is a player first to act. does this person have more or less chips than the other player? does this same player check or go all-in?

Answer (score 0):

the river is always dealt in any circumstance when a player is all-in.

the other player can call up to the maximum amount the the all-in player is in for.then the hand continues to be dealt and no further action can be taken. the players definitely have the option of turning over their cards before all the cards are dealt in this situation, but no matter what ALL cards are dealt.

note that under situations where there are more than 2 players involved and either 1 or more of them are all-in, a side pot is usually generated. any further chip action now belongs to the side pot(s) that correspond to each individual's stack.